# For what values of n does the following in equation has no solution?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

### CONTEXT

So recently I have worked out this: Prove that the equation $x^2-y^3=7$ has no integral solution.

I have also solved this question: Prove that there are infinitely number of integral $n$ so that the equation $x^2-y^3=n$ has no integral solution.

By setting $n= (4k+2)^3-1$, and the proof is showing that $x^2+1$ has at least one prime divisor in the form of $p=4q+3$, $q \in \mathbb{Z} $, $p \in \mathbb{P} $, which is an obvious contradiction because of the following corollary:

If $a^2+b^2$ is divisible by $p$ ( $p$ is defined as above ) then both $a$ and $b$ is divisible by $p$.

### QUESTION

Is there any method to point out **all** the values of $n$ satisfying the problem rather than just one **infinite case** ?

Comment: In general, it is very difficult to solve $x^2-y^3=N$ completely or even only to determine whether a solution exist. In some cases, the smallest solution will be huge. Elliptic curves is not an easy stuff.

Comment: @Peter, but I think it should be more simple to determine **only** the case when the equation has no solution? I mean, it is not that we have to solve the equation in general do we?